# Parse4j error JAVA Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, parse4j

I use parse4j to let user sign up an account and sign in so User can view Their score online the problem is I cannot run my app and It says a lot of error

I import the parse4j-1.0.jar file to my eclipse project and I write as the instruction

This is my code

```
    package com.card.lab;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import org.parse4j.ParseException;
import org.parse4j.ParseUser;
import org.parse4j.callback.LoginCallback;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import org.parse4j.callback.*;
import org.parse4j.*;

public class SignIN extends JFrame{
    JTextField user = new JTextField();
    JTextField pass = new JTextField();
    JButton signIn = new JButton();
    JButton signUp = new JButton();
      ParseUser userr = new ParseUser();
      ParseUser sign = new ParseUser();

      LoginCallback back;
    SignIN(){
        Parse.initialize("jNKMBNdtX5Vq9tS6jVsNLEO89fvZQ1el2D3xnTeP","ZnhzdUVXXaiDGQRfn1lOXifclxSFQDW18Y7gbQBb");
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
        this.setBackground(new Color(222,252,226));
      this.setSize(400,400);
      signIn.setText("SIGN IN");
      signUp.setText("SIGN UP");
      this.add(user);
      this.add(pass);
      this.add(signIn);
      this.add(signUp);
      this.setVisible(true);
      signUp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            userr.setUsername(user.getText());
            userr.setPassword(pass.getText());
            try {
                userr.signUp();
                userr.loginInBackground(user.getText(), pass.getText(),back);
                if(sign!=null){
                    System.out.println("LOG IN");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("ERROR SIGN IN");
                }
                dispatch();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

      });
      signIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign.loginInBackground(user.getText(), pass.getText(),back);
            if(sign!=null){
                System.out.println("LOG IN");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("ERROR SIGN IN");
            }
        }

      });
    }
    public void dispatch(){
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          new SignIN();
    }

}
```

and the errors are

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
    at com.card.lab.SignIN.<init>(SignIN.java:24)
    at com.card.lab.SignIN.main(SignIN.java:87)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

I don't understand why this happen

Any help is appreciated, let me know if you need any additional information!

Thank you

UPDATE

I've import parse4j-1.0.jar and json-20150729.jar and the error has changed to

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.parse4j.ParseObject.<clinit>(ParseObject.java:42)
    at com.card.lab.SignIN.<init>(SignIN.java:25)
    at com.card.lab.SignIN.main(SignIN.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1):

`parse4j` has a JSON dependency whose [jar file](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20150729/json-20150729.jar) needs to be on the classpath when running the application. If youre using Maven you can simply use the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.thiagolocatelli</groupId>
    <artifactId>parse4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I import jar file into my project with add external jar button in eclipse, anything else that I have to do? Thanks

Comment: If the jar file is on the classpath then that's all you need to do (although I would have included the file directly to the project as a 'regular' jar)

Comment: But the error is still exist any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: By the way, I imported parse4j-1.0.jar

Comment: yes but you need to import `json-20150729.jar` as well

Comment: I did it but the error is still shown any suggestions? thanks

Comment: different jar missing now: you need the SLF4J implementation .jar `slf4j-api.jar`

Answer (score 0):

From [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)

> NoClassDefFoundError is thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a
>   ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as
>   part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance
>   using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be
>   found. The searched-for class definition existed when the currently
>   executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be
>   found.